# Sticky Bootstrap Navbar and Smooth-Scroll - Padding / Margin-Top

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, smooth-scrolling

I'm trying to implement a **bootstrap sticky navbar** (fixed height of 81px) with **smooth-scroll behavior**.

The HTML site features section tags, such as `<section class="section" id="news">`, which works in order to jump to certain areas by using `<a class="nav-link" href="#news">News</a>` in the navbar. I am using the following CSS and JS technologies, which load at the beginning of the `<body>`:

- https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/navbar/
- https://github.com/iamdustan/smoothscroll
- https://github.com/jonaskuske/smoothscroll-anchor-polyfill

So far it works: at the bootstrap specific `--breakpoint-lg` at 992px, the navbar collapses into a burger menu. In order to compensate for the fixed-height navbar, I added the following code to my `custom.css` (loaded after the `bootstrap.min.css` of course), according to a trick found at https://css-tricks.com/fixed-headers-on-page-links-and-overlapping-content-oh-my/

```
@media (max-width: 991px) {
    section {
        padding-top: 382px;
        margin-top: -382px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
    section {
        padding-top: 80px;
        margin-top: -80px;
    }
}
```

This works fine on larger dimensions of the browser window width, but **as soon as it's loaded on smaller width windows** (991px and below) - on almost all mobile devices - clicking the navbar-link jumps to a point slightly vertically offset. **Any ideas why this happens? It seems my media-query for max-width: 991px is being ignored.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your advice of creating a **snippet**. This **shows the working trick** by use of background colors for the individual divs within the sections. This way the very first element (a h2-heading) is at the top of each area that we jump to. When not using background-colors this totally works for the viewer and reader of the continous text with h2-headers in between.

I think I found a **satisfying solution**. My problem with the `padding-top / margin-top` trick was: instead of (correctly) styling the `<div class="container" id="first">` in the CSS, I styled the `<section>`. Eventually, I also did not need the `@media` query anymore.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".nav-link").click(function() {
    let nav = $(".navbar-collapse");
    if (nav.hasClass("show")) {
      nav.removeClass("show");
    }
  })
})
```

```css
html {
  --scroll-behavior: smooth;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  font-family: 'scroll-behavior: smooth;', sans-serif;
}

.container {
  padding-top: 80px;
  margin-top: -80px;
}

p {
  line-height: 2em;
}

.navbar {
  background: lightgoldenrodyellow;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
}

#first {
  background-color: lightcoral;
}

#second {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

#third {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

#fourth {
  background-color: lightgray;
}

#fifth {
  background-color: lightyellow;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="zxx">

<head>
  <title>bootstrap / breakpoint / smooth-scroll issue</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="custom.css">
</head>

<body>

  <!-- JS -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.0/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery.easing@1.4.1/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/smoothscroll@0.4.0/smoothscroll.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/smoothscroll-anchor-polyfill@1.3.4/dist/index.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>

  <!-- Navigation Start -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg sticky-top">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
            </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto navbar-center">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#first">First</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#second">Second</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#third">Third</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#fourth">Fourth</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#fifth">Fifth</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <!-- Navigation End -->

  <!-- Content Start -->
  <section class="section">
    <div class="container" id="first">
      <h3>first</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
        elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
        labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur
        sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
        veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt
        in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section class="section">
    <div class="container" id="second">
      <h3>second</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
        elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
        labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur
        sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
        veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt
        in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section class="section">
    <div class="container" id="third">
      <h3>third</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
        elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
        labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur
        sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
        veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt
        in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section class="section">
    <div class="container" id="fourth">
      <h3>fourth</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
        elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
        labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur
        sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
        veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt
        in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section class="section">
    <div class="container" id="fifth">
      <h3>fifth</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
        elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
        labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur
        sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
        veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt
        in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
  </section>
  <!-- Content End -->

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Nice. Glad you got it sorted. Be sure to accept your answer to resolve this post.